# Can I create private eth network that no external one can join it?

Tags: blockchain, go-ethereum

I want to run predfined 10 eth miners on private network so no one can enter the network except the 10 miners that I want.

I initialized a network using geth and I enabled --nodiscover option.
Is that enough to secure my network ?

Note: the network is on internet not local network

Answer (score 0):

Maybe possible if someone who knows enode and IP address of any one of your node tries.

If you want predefined 10 miners only, you may run geth with tag "--maxpeers 10"